# Felling a tree in a random direction?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I cannot figure out how to make a tree with a random Y-rotation fall after cutting it down. I want it to fall until it is perpendicular to the ground (90 degrees), but I want it to be random which direction it falls in.

The pivot is on the bottom of the tree, so if I just rotate Z-axis to 90 degrees then it looks like it falls, but I want to randomize the direction, I tried some stuff but its not doing what I expect:

```
public void Fall(float duration)
{
    int xOrZ = Random.Range(0, 1);
    float randomRot = Random.Range(0,90);

    Vector3 rotation = Vector3.zero;

    if (xOrZ == 0)
        rotation = new Vector3(90, 0, randomRot);
    else
        rotation = new Vector3(randomRot, 0, 90);

    mTransform.DORotate(rotation, duration);
}
```

I figured if I make sure one of the axis is 90 then it will always fall to the ground but that didnt work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the pivot of your object is at the bottom, it is easier to `Lerp` the `transform.up` vector of the tree GameObject in a way that it starts to tilt. You can pick a point inside a unit circle using Unity's `Random.InsideUnitCircle`. This would return a `Vector2`, then you can multiply each component with your right and forward vectors to find where the tip of the tree will be when it falls. Now, the vector between the tree object's position and the falling point should be your new up vector for the tree object. Then you can run a simple Coroutine that Lerps the up vector of the tree object to the newly calculated up vector. The `Lerp` allows you to define the duration and you can cut the Coroutine off once the distance between the desired up vector and the current up vector is below a certain threshold. If you use this code and call the Fall function just as you desired it would work:

```
    using System.Collections; // for IEnumerator

    public GameObject treeObject; // assuming this is your tree object

    public void Fall(float duration)
    {
        // pick a random point on the circle to match the up vector
        Vector2 pointOnCircle = UnityEngine.Random.insideUnitCircle * treeObject.transform.localScale.y;

        // find the fall point, assuming the pivot of the object is at the bottom
        Vector3 fallPoint = treeObject.transform.position + 
            pointOnCircle.x * treeObject.transform.right + 
            pointOnCircle.y * treeObject.transform.forward;

        // find the target up vector
        Vector3 updatedUpVector = Vector3.Normalize(fallPoint - treeObject.transform.position);

        // Start the coroutine to tilt the up vector to the desired target
        StartCoroutine(UpdateUpVector(treeObject, updatedUpVector, duration, 0.001f));
    }

    public IEnumerator UpdateUpVector(GameObject target, Vector3 upVector, float duration, float threshold = 0.001f)
    {
        // the target vector and up vector would get closer to each other until the threshold is hit
        while(Vector3.Distance(upVector, target.transform.up) > threshold)
        {
            target.transform.up = Vector3.Lerp(target.transform.up, upVector, duration * Time.deltaTime);
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        }
    }
```

The code above results with this, using a cylinder whose pivot is at the bottom. Notice that the tree is falling towards the random point on the unit circle that is around the `transform.position` of the tree object.:

[image: Notice that the tree is falling towards the random point on the unit circle that is around the <code>transform.position</code> of the tree object.]